# What is the proper way to store an array into a database table?

Tags: sql, database, arrays, ms-access

I have an array of 50+ elements that dictates how many hours were worked for a given week.

What is the proper way to store this information into a database table?

My initial idea was to use a delimiter, but the text is too large (280 characters) to fit.

Additionally, there seems something "wrong" with creating a table column for each element.

Ideas?

Array using delimiter (comma):
37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5,37.5, ...

Comment: What is the structure of your array? A week has 7 days. Why do you have 50+ elements? Show us the structure.

Comment: How about a new table with a `weeknumber` column and an `hours` column?

Comment: @Petar I'm tracking 56 weeks in a year (hours are stored by weeks, not by day)

Comment: Very simplified: one element in your array => one row in a database table

Comment: A crucial question is whether your SQL product has array data types. This question has been tagged "access": if the SQL product in question is Microsoft Office Access (and if so retag using "ms-access") then it does support [multi-valued types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/guide-to-multivalued-fields-HA001233722.aspx) but note its SQL syntax lacks operators to query elements in a multi-valued column.

Comment: For future designing, it is virtually never the right answer to store an array in one field. This is the worst possible way to store data in a database. each field should contain one and only one piece of information per row.

Comment: @HLGEM: unless the domain in question is a set of arrays and the DBMS supports an array data type (as does MS Access).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "proper" way is to store the array's contents as multiple rows in a whole other table, each with a foreign key referencing the record they belong to back in the first table. There may be other things that work for you, though.

[EDIT]: From the details you added I'm guessing your array elements consist of a number of hours worked each week and you have 50+ of them because a year has 52-ish weeks. So what I think you're looking for, is I guess that your current (main) table is called something like "employees," is that each row there should have some unique identifier for each employee record. So your new table might be called "work_weeks" and consist of something like employee_id (which matches the employee id in the current table), week_number, and hours_worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a 1 to many relationship.  For this example, tableA is the 1 and tableBlammo is the many.

tableA => column blammoId

tableBlammo => column blammoId, column data

One row in tableA joins to multiple rows in tableBlammo via the blammoId column.
Each row in tableBlammo has one element of the array in the data column.